# Run as admin the shortcut from startup

Tags: wix, shortcut

I created shortcut in the Startup folder. Is it possible to add "Run as administrator" property for my shortcut by wix? here my code:

```
<Component Id="AutostartService" Guid="GUID">  
    <Condition>AUTOSTART="1"</Condition>  
    <RegistryKey Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" Root="HKCU"
                 Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)\$(var.ApplicationName)">  
        <RegistryValue Name="ShortcutAutostart"
                       Type="integer" Value="1"
                       KeyPath="yes">  
        </RegistryValue>  
    </RegistryKey>  
    <Shortcut Advertise="no" Directory="StartupFolder"
              Name="Service"
              Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]Service.exe"  
              Id="SHORTCUT_auto"  
              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION" >  
    </Shortcut>  
    <RemoveFile Id="remove_autostart" Name="Service"   On="uninstall"/>  
</Component>
```

Comment: Are you building the application that your shortcut points to, or is it something for which you don't have the source code?

Comment: Do you want *Run as administrator* command in context menu of the shortcut? Or do you want the shortcut to start your application elevated (with administrator privileges) when system starts? — The latter would not work.

Comment: Yeah, I want to use this command in context menu of the shortcut. And I don't have the source code for the executable.

Comment: If you only want *Run as administrator* command to be shown in your shortcut context menu, check that your shortcut is non-advertised: right-click it and then click *Properties*. *Target* should be the path to the executable. Looking at your WiX code, I would think it is the case and hence the command should be displayed in the context menu.

Comment: Thanks, i thought if there is any way to enable "Run as" checkbox in shortcut's Properties during install, but it seems that I want more than it possible

Comment: You can implement a custom action that changes the shortcut flags, see [How to install a desktop shortcut from a WiX-based installer that has "Run as Administrator" enabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633090/how-to-install-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-batch-file-from-a-wix-based-installer-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not supported, because it's ["the wrong thing to do."](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071219-00/?p=24103)

Comment: The link is now a 404.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20070118143250/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/library/en-us/dnlong/html/AccProtVista.asp